# Papertrail throwing error as "dhclient: XMT: Solicit on eth0"?

Tags: centos, papertrail-app, dhclient

In **Papertrail**, while accessing the link through browser, it will be capture in papertrail log, but unfortunately it is not capture. It keep on throwing error as "**dhclient: XMT: Solicit on eth0**" in **centos server**. Any idea to resolve this one?

```
Aug 29 19:52:36 test.com dhclient: XMT: Solicit on eth0, interval 131820ms.
Aug 29 19:54:48 test.com dhclient: XMT: Solicit on eth0, interval 113800ms.
Aug 29 19:54:48 test.com dhclient: XMT: Solicit on eth0, interval 113800ms.
Aug 29 19:56:42 test.com dhclient: XMT: Solicit on eth0, interval 109530ms.
Aug 29 19:56:42 test.com dhclient: XMT: Solicit on eth0, interval 109530ms.
Aug 29 19:58:32 test.com dhclient: XMT: Solicit on eth0, interval 129740ms.
Aug 29 19:58:32 test.com dhclient: XMT: Solicit on eth0, interval 129740ms.
```

Even if am trying to access below commands also throwing same error.

```
sudo tail -f /var/log/messages
```

Answer (score 0):

That's dhclient looking for an IPv6 address.  If there is no DHCPv6 server on your network, it will never get one.  You can disable IPv6 on the interface if it's bothering you.